# Outputting array values with a constant size declarator

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, parallel-arrays

In my program 3 out of the 4 functions will not run all the way through and it seems to have something to do with my arrays.

They all seem to fail when it tries to out put the array that contains names. I was wondering if I could some how be trying to output the array incorrectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double FastSkier(double [], string[], int);     //Function for finding fastest skier
double AvgTime(double[], int);                  //Function for finding Average
int SpecTime(double[], string[], int);          //Function for finding the time of the name entered
int SkiAndTime(double[], string[], int);        //Function to list all Skiers and their times

int main()
{
const int Size = 5; //size of arrays
//int fastest;  //variable for FastSkier function: fastest skier
//double Avg;       //Average
double time[Size] = { 2.03, 2.40, 1.85, 1.90, 2.50 };   //array for Skier times
string name[Size] = { "Leela", "Sarah", "Anna", "Keesha", "Heidi" };    //array for Skier names
//int Loc;      //assignment variable to for locations within arrays
int choice;

for (int count = 1;; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter 1 to find the fastest Skier" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 for the average time of the Skiers" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 to find the time of a specific Skier \n";
    cout << "Enter 4 to display all Skiers and their times \n";
    cout << "\n";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
        FastSkier(time, name, Size);
    else if (choice == 2)
        AvgTime(time, Size);
    else if (choice == 3)
        SpecTime(time, name, Size);
    else if (choice == 4)
        SkiAndTime(time, name, Size);
    else
        break;

}
system ("pause");
return 0;
}



double FastSkier(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
int Loc;    //location of data within array, value determined by for-loop
double fastest=time[0]; //variable to find fastest time for Skier, initialized at first value of time
for (Loc = 1; Loc < Size; Loc++)    //cycles through all values of time comparing each one to find the lowest value
{
    if (time[Loc] < fastest)
        fastest = time[Loc];
}
cout << "The fastest Skier is " << name[Loc] << " with a time of " << time[Loc] << endl;
return 0;
}


double AvgTime(double time[], int Size)
{
int Loc;    //location of data within array, acts as a counter in this function 
double Avg; //Average
double sum = 0; //sum of all values within time[]

for (Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)
    sum += time[Loc];
Avg = sum / Size;

cout << "The average time for Skiers is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << Avg << endl;
cout << "\n";
cout << "\n";
return 0;
}


int SpecTime(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
string Skier;
cout << "Skiers \n";
cout << "    " << name[Size] << endl;

cout << "Enter the name of the Skier to view their time \n";
cin >> Skier;

for (int Loc = 0; Loc < Size; Loc++)
{
    if (Skier == name[Loc])
    {
        cout << Skier << " has the time " << time[Loc] << endl;
        break;
    }
    /*else
        while (Skier != name[Loc])
        {
            cout << "The name you entered is not a current competitor in this competition \n";
            cout << "Please enter a name from the list \n";
            cin >> Skier;
        }*/
}
return 0;
}


int SkiAndTime(double time[], string name[], int Size)
{
cout << "Skiers             Times" << endl;
cout << name[Size] << "           " << time[Size] << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fastest Skier ends up accessing index 5, which is out of bounds

Comment: how would you suggest avoiding this?

Comment: Put the statement with the fastest skier inside the loop. Once you exit the loop the index is incremented

Comment: What of the other two functions?

Comment: In the function FastSkier, move the two lines with cout inside the loop. In general, check your indices and never use them after a loop.